# Git push heroku master failed

Tags: git

I had some problems about Git push heroku master.

I type the command at Git Bash.

```
$ git push heroku master
```

and this is the error log:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T10Ue.png)

How could I fix it ?

Comment: Please include the error message and any relevant code *as text in your question*.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is right there in the output:

```
./main.go:50: message declared and not used
```

- ./main.go:50 *see line 50 of main.go*
- message declared and not used  *unused variables are not allowed in go*

Before deploying to heroku, you should test your program compiles locally first, you'll see the same error when running locally.